# непонятные знаки при чтении файла

Tags: c, файлы, обработка-ошибок

Есть подобный вопрос на эту тему, но ответа для своего случая не нашел. Стоит задача: . Компоненты бинарного файла – вещественные числа. Нормировать компоненты файла вычитанием среднего арифметического всех чисел из каждого числа.
Для создания исходного бинарного файла написать отдельную программу, в программе его обработки выводить на экран содержимое файла до и после изменения.
Программа:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void output(FILE* file, int y);
void srarif(double mas[], double summa, double sred);
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    double x, sr, sum=0, a[128];
    int ch;
    FILE* f = fopen("lab7_2.txt", "wb+");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
        exit(1);
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        x = rand() % 10;
        a[i] = x;
        fwrite(&x, sizeof(x), 1, f);
        fprintf(f," - %lf ",x);
        //fprintf(f, "%lf ", x);
        //fprintf(f, "%c", space);
    }
    fclose(f);
    output(f, ch);
    printf("\n");
    srarif(a, sum, sr);
    f = fopen("lab7_2.txt", "wb");
    if(!f){
    printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
    exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        fwrite(&a[i], sizeof(a), 1, f);
        fprintf(f, " - %lf ", a[i]);
        //fprintf(f, "%lf ", x);
        //fprintf(f, "%c", space);
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("\n");
    output(f, ch);
    return 0;
}
void output(FILE* file, int y) {
    file = fopen("lab7_2.txt", "rb");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(file) && !ferror(file))
    {
        y = getc(file);
        if (y != EOF)
        {
            putchar(y);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
void srarif(double mas[], double summa, double sred) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        summa += mas[i];
    }
    sred = summa / 11;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        mas[i] -= sred;
    }
}
```

Когда запускаю программу, в консоли появляется множество одинакового символа, который находится между тем, что по факту должно быть в файле(см.фото).
[image: strange]

На всякий случай исходник без функций:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    double x, sr, sum=0, a[128];
    int ch;
    FILE* f = fopen("lab7_2.txt", "wb+");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
        exit(1);
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        x = rand() % 10;
        a[i] = x;
        fwrite(&x, sizeof(x), 1, f);
        fprintf(f," - %lf ",x);
        //fprintf(f, "%lf ", x);
        //fprintf(f, "%c", space);
    }
    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("lab7_2.txt", "rb");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(f) && !ferror(f))
    {
        ch = getc(f);
        if (ch != EOF)
        {
            putchar(ch);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    sr = sum / 11;
    printf("%lf", sr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        a[i] -= sr;
    }
    f = fopen("lab7_2.txt", "wb");
    if(!f){
    printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
    exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        fwrite(&a[i], sizeof(a), 1, f);
        fprintf(f, " - %lf ", a[i]);
        //fprintf(f, "%lf ", x);
        //fprintf(f, "%c", space);
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("\n");
    f = fopen("lab7_2.txt", "rb");
    if (!f) {
        printf("Не удалось открыть файл");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(f) && !ferror(f))
    {
        ch = getc(f);
        if (ch != EOF)
        {
            putchar(ch);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так... вам все же нужно бинарное представление, что ж тогда вы удивлялись в предыдущем вопросе?!

Comment: @harry на самом деле, с вашим ответом получилось даже лучше, потому что так, я смог проверить на правильность выполнения программы(до появления ошибки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void create()
{
    FILE * f = fopen("data.in","wb");
    int count = rand()%20+10; // От 10 до 30 чисел
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        double x = rand()*1000.0/RAND_MAX; // От 0 до 1000
        fwrite(&x,sizeof(x),1,f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    // Создание файла
    create();

    // Чтение файла, вывод, подсчет среднего
    FILE* in = fopen("data.in","rb");
    int count = 0;
    double x, avg = 0;
    while(fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,in)==1)
    {
        count++;
        avg+= x;
        printf("%lf  ",x);
    }
    printf("\n\nAverage = %lf\n\n", avg /= count);
    fseek(in,0,SEEK_SET);
    FILE * out = fopen("data.out","wb");
    while(fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,in)==1)
    {
        x -= avg;
        printf("%lf  ",x);
        fwrite(&x,sizeof(x),1,out);
    }
    puts("\n\n");
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
}
```

Защиту от дурака (все проверки и т.п.) для краткости не писал.

Только не пытайтесь искать обычные десятичные числа, открывая создаваемые файлы в каком-нибудь "блокноте". Это **бинарные** файлы, как и требовалось. Их содержимое — числа в том виде, в котором они хранятся в памяти компьютера, что-то вроде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему тип файла именно in?

Comment: Да пишите что угодно. Я назвал in и out просто чтоб бьло понятно, что один входной, другой выходной...

Comment: я про расширение файла data.in

Comment: Так и я о нем же.